# Is it possible to refer label in another testcase in selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have multiple testcases. I want one of my test cases point to a label in previous test case. Is it possible to refer label in another testcase in selenium IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Yes; you can do this using any `store*` command.

Suppose you are able get required label's text in your 1st test case, store it in a variable `label` :

```
|storeText | PreviousTestsLabelLocator | label |
```

Then in your 2nd test (or another test) access the previously stored "label" using `${label}`
For example, just print it:

```
|echo | ${label} | |
```